# How does the model know what my data is labeled as?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a piece of code here:.   
I want to know how the model knows how pictures are labeled.

I don't find any labeling function in the code and the dog-cat data directories are just full of images. I would like to solve the problem here so that I use this model for a different dataset. Just don't know how to label it.

Edit: A better way to phrase this is: How does this script in particular know how my images are labeled as, when each test, train, and validation directory is randomized and does not have any indication in the file names as to what its label is?

```
#Importing a pre-trained network
#Running from end to end with fine-tuning
from keras.applications import ResNet50
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
#Fix memory growth issue
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)




#Summoning pretrained network
#Top is the classifier (Dense layer) which we want to change
#Using imagenet weights
conv_base = ResNet50(weights= 'imagenet',
                 include_top= False, 
                 input_shape= (150, 150, 3))


#Directories
test_dir = r''
train_dir = r'C:\Users\17574\Downloads\dogs-vs-cats\Training'
valid_dir = r'C:\Users\17574\Downloads\dogs-vs-cats\Validation'



#Network
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


#Fine tuning
conv_base.trainable = True
#Go through each layer. If layer is conv1, set it to trainable. Rest false
set_trainable = False
for layer in conv_base.layers:
    if layer.name == 'block5_conv1':
        set_trainable = True
    if set_trainable:
        layer.trainable = True
    else:
        layer.trainable = False





#Data augmentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=40,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')


# Note that the test data should not be augmented!
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)



#Generator that takes images and runs it through the data augmentation
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        # This is the target directory
        train_dir,
        # All images will be resized to 150x150
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
        class_mode='binary')


validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary')


#Use RMS prop to avoid doing big changes to weights
#We do not want to harm already trained weights too much
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-5),
              metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=100,
      epochs=100,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=50)



history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=100,
      epochs=30,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=50,
      verbose=2)


#model.save('cats_and_dogs_small_4.h5')


acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs = range(len(acc))

plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'bo', label='Training acc')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'b', label='Validation acc')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend()

plt.figure()

plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'bo', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.legend()

plt.show()



test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary')

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, steps=50)
print('test acc:', test_acc)
```

Comment: it classifies on folders names and there classification.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/):

> **Arguments**
>
> **labels**: Either "inferred" (labels are generated from the directory structure), or a list/tuple of integer labels of the same size as the number of image files found in the directory. Labels should be sorted according to the alphanumeric order of the image file paths (obtained via os.walk(directory) in Python).

To put it more concisely, if your directory structure is:

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......a_image_1.jpg
......a_image_2.jpg
...class_b/
......b_image_1.jpg
......b_image_2.jpg
```

...then calling `image_dataset_from_directory(main_directory, labels='inferred')` will return a dataset of images from the subdirectories `class_a` and `class_b`, together with labels 0 and 1 (0 corresponding to class_a and 1 corresponding to class_b).

So the labels are inferred from the folders. You can of course specify which folders to include.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that tensorflow will know that the first folder will be labeled as a 0 and the second folder will be labeled as a 1 correct? And looking at the documentation (I should have done that first, sorry) I will be able to shuffle my data as well. I will try that

Comment: Yes you can even get the order with a certain method.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take an example:
Suppose you downloaded dogVcat dataset from kaggle.
So the directory will be:

**FOR TRAINING SET**
*Downloads/dataset/training_set/cats* : This will be labeled as 0 as it is first folder in the directory.
*Downloads/dataset/training_set/cats* : This will be labeled as 1 as it is second folder in the directory.

**FOR VALIDATION SET**
*Downloads/dataset/validation_set/cats* : This will be labeled as 0.
*Downloads/dataset/validation_set/dogs* : This will be labeled as 1.

This all is done by **flow_from_directory()** function which is present in ImageDataGenerator class.